# CSS hovering a class with the same classname (not known in advance)

Tags: html, css, hover, selector

I have several pairs of divs that need to be highlighted as soon someone hovers over one of those two elements. They can be identified with a classname that is not known in advance. e.g:

```
<div class="highlight h19_209">...</div>
...
<div class="highlight h19_209">...</div>
```

The class `h19_209` is generated on the fly and is based on two IDs. The divs can be located somewhere on the page. Is there a way to do it purely using CSS?

Comment: "Is there a way to do it purely using CSS?" No, there is not.

Comment: If the divs are somewhere on the page I don't think pure CSS can do it.

Comment: `.highlight:hover { }` or `div[class^=h]:hover {}` perhaps?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what your scenario is. What two IDs are the classes based on? What does the markup look up *including* the elements with these two IDs? Either way, this is something you'll need JavaScript for since it is dynamic.

Comment: Do you mean if someone hovers over one element with the class `highlight` all elements with this class should get the `:hover` properties?

Comment: @elveti I cannot select any element starting with "h" but only those that have the exact same class

Comment: @TylerH I have to build a tool to vizualize differences between two files. So if a line moved its position from one file to another, I want to highlight the pair as soon as one hovers over one of the two lines. The IDs are based on the position in file1 and file2.

Comment: If those element are generated on the fly, generate also the css that goes along meanwhile ..